# How to make a auto status for the date and time

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Using SQL Server 2005

Table1

Leave Table

```
ID startDate EndDate

001 21/01/2013 20/02/2013
002 24/01/2013 13/02/2013
```

Table2

```
ID DATE  TIME STATUS

001 21/01/2013 NULL ANNUAL
001 22/01/2013 NULL 
001 23/01/2013 NULL 
001 24/01/2013 NULL  Holiday (Sunday)
001 25/01/2013 02:00 Present
```

In table 2 i want to display the status as absent, after annual leave folling condition should display in the system

1) After annual leave, system display as "ABSENT" because annual leave extended upto time available row
2) Holiday also should show as absent because time is not available.

System display as absent in between annaul leave end date from table 1 and time available row in table 2

Expected Output

```
ID DATE  TIME STATUS

001 21/01/2013 NULL ANNUAL
001 22/01/2013 NULL Absent
001 23/01/2013 NULL Absent
001 24/01/2013 NULL  Absent 
001 25/01/2013 02:00 Present
```

How to make a query for the following condition.  Need Query Help.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite difficult to understand your question, but how close is this?

```
SELECT 
T2.ID, T2.Date, T2.Time, 
CASE 
WHEN T2.Date = T1.startDate THEN 'Annual'
WHEN T2.Date BETWEEN T1.startDate AND T2.endDate THEN 'Absent'
END Status
FROM 
Table2 T2
LEFT OUTER JOIN
Table1 T1
ON  T2.ID = T1.ID
AND T2.Date BETWEEN T1.startDate AND T2.endDate
WHERE T2.ID = '001'
```